# Angular 2 File Upload directive, max concurrent uploads limit

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am exploring the below Angular 2 directive for file upload. When trying the

**ng-file-select directive**

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';
import { Ng2Uploader } from '../services/ng2-uploader';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngFileSelect]'
})
export class NgFileSelectDirective {

  @Input() events: EventEmitter<any>;
  @Output() onUpload: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onPreviewData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  _options:any;

  get options(): any {
    return this._options;
  }

  @Input('options')
  set options(value: any) {
    this._options = value;
    this.uploader.setOptions(this.options);
  }

  files: any[] = [];
  uploader: Ng2Uploader;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    this.uploader = new Ng2Uploader();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.uploader.setOptions(this.options);
    });

    this.uploader._emitter.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.onUpload.emit(data);
      if (data.done) {
        this.files = this.files.filter(f => f.name !== data.originalName);
      }
    });

    this.uploader._previewEmitter.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.onPreviewData.emit(data);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.events) {
        this.events.subscribe((data: string) => {
          if (data === 'startUpload') {
            this.uploader.uploadFilesInQueue();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  filterFilesByExtension(): void {
    this.files = this.files.filter(f => {
      if (this.options.allowedExtensions.indexOf(f.type) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }

      let ext: string = f.name.split('.').pop();
      if (this.options.allowedExtensions.indexOf(ext) !== -1 ) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    });
  }

  @HostListener('change') onChange(): void {
    this.files = Array.from(this.el.nativeElement.files);
    if (this.options.filterExtensions && this.options.allowedExtensions) {
      this.filterFilesByExtension();
    }

    if (this.files.length) {
      this.uploader.addFilesToQueue(this.files);
    }
  }
}
```

**ng-file-select service**

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
  HostListener
} from '@angular/core';
import { Ng2Uploader } from '../services/ng2-uploader';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngFileSelect]'
})
export class NgFileSelectDirective {

  @Input() events: EventEmitter<any>;
  @Output() onUpload: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onPreviewData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  _options:any;

  get options(): any {
    return this._options;
  }

  @Input('options')
  set options(value: any) {
    this._options = value;
    this.uploader.setOptions(this.options);
  }

  files: any[] = [];
  uploader: Ng2Uploader;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    this.uploader = new Ng2Uploader();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.uploader.setOptions(this.options);
    });

    this.uploader._emitter.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.onUpload.emit(data);
      if (data.done) {
        this.files = this.files.filter(f => f.name !== data.originalName);
      }
    });

    this.uploader._previewEmitter.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.onPreviewData.emit(data);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.events) {
        this.events.subscribe((data: string) => {
          if (data === 'startUpload') {
            this.uploader.uploadFilesInQueue();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  filterFilesByExtension(): void {
    this.files = this.files.filter(f => {
      if (this.options.allowedExtensions.indexOf(f.type) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }

      let ext: string = f.name.split('.').pop();
      if (this.options.allowedExtensions.indexOf(ext) !== -1 ) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    });
  }

  @HostListener('change') onChange(): void {
    this.files = Array.from(this.el.nativeElement.files);
    if (this.options.filterExtensions && this.options.allowedExtensions) {
      this.filterFilesByExtension();
    }

    if (this.files.length) {
      this.uploader.addFilesToQueue(this.files);
    }
  }
}
```

When providing the options:

```
this.options = {
      url: 'http://api.ng2-uploader.com:10050/upload',
      filterExtensions: true,
      allowedExtensions: ['image/png', 'image/jpg'],
      calculateSpeed: true,
      multiple:true,
      maxUploads:1,
      data: {
        userId: 12,
        isAdmin: true
      },
      customHeaders: {
        'custom-header': 'value'
      },
      authToken: 'asd123b123zxc08234cxcv',
      authTokenPrefix: 'Bearer'
    };
```

**Source**: https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader

I want to allow multiple file uploads, but 1 files should be uploaded one by one.

Currently there doesn't seems to be any handling for this in above directive. Can any one please guide where and how this limit should be imposed in the service.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just have to use the plain html [multiple](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) attribute like

```
<input type="file" ngFileSelect [options]="options" multiple>
```

Comment: Yes that allows multiple uploads, but I want the files to be uploaded one after other.

Comment: Oh ok, like a queue. I did not completly understand your needs :/

Comment: Yes exactly, so that I can update the preview image of each selected file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) directive. It performs the multiple file upload, by adding them to a queue and then uploading each in a separate request.